# Is it safe to call [subview setNeedsDisplay] inside [superview drawRect:]?

Tags: ios, uiview, uikit, drawrect

I'm using `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentContext` inside `drawRect` and setting a subview's property to the returned `UIImage`. This ends up triggering `setNeedsDisplay` in the subview.

Can this have any side effects?

Basically, will the subview always have its `drawRect` method called if `setNeedsDisplay` was called within the superview's `drawRect` method? Or would the subview be considered "already displayed", meaning no update will take place?

Answer (score 1):

From the mailing list: http://lists.apple.com/archives/Cocoa-dev/2005/Jul/msg01697.html

> If you call setNeedsDisplay: from within drawRect:, the flag will be set, but as soon as drawRect: returns, it will be cleared again.  Therefore, when the time arrives, the flag is clear and drawRect: is not called again.
>
> -drawRect should only be used for drawing.  Resizing, repositioning, and adding or removing subviews absolutely should not be done in drawRect:.  Incorrect behavior will likely result.  The AppKit reasonably relies on the view hierarchy remaining constant while it is in the middle of drawing the view hierarchy.
>
> Furthermore, do not call -display or variants or -drawRect from within drawRect: or you invite an infinite recursion and crash.

The above snippet is answering this question: http://lists.apple.com/archives/Cocoa-dev/2005/Jul/msg01693.html

> ### Overview
>
> I have an NSView (viewA) that manages multiple subviews.  This view's
>   drawRect contains code that positions and sizes all of its subviews
>   accordingly and calls each of the subview's setNeedsDisplay:YES
>   method.  One of the subviews is also an NSView (viewB), and it also
>   has multiple subviews.
>
> ### Problem
>
> If the window that contains viewA is resized, viewA's drawRect method
>   is invoked, but for some unknown reason, viewB's drawRect method is
>   not always invoked, despite the fact that viewA's drawRect method
>   invokes viewB's setNeedsDisplay:YES method.  The drawRect method
>   associated with all of viewA's other subviews are invoked though.
>
> ### Question
>
> Can anyone suggest any reasons as to why viewB's drawRect method is
>   not always called after its superview sends it a setNeedsDisplay
>   message?  Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong would be appreciated.